# How to add logo to a WordPress Custom Plugin?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I am trying to add a LOGO for my custom WordPress plugin, that I have created for a specific website. I have searched everywhere, and I have found nothing. What are the functions or hooks, that I have to use? Please if possible show me code examples.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by a logo for your plugin? What kind of logo? For what purpose? Where would it appear?

Comment: I want to appear in the page where there are only the plugins for update. Link - wp-admin/update-core.php. From left dashboard menu is UPDATES link

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are referring about plugin icons. Actually these icons are not adding in plugin folder. These are coming from from wordpress account. When you upload plugin into wordpress plugin repository, icons and images are upload to `assets` directory of your SVN directory. You can add icon as icon-256x256.png and it will appear in core update page.

Reference: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-org/plugin-assets/